# Comparison between threading module and multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

So I am trying to compare whether **threading** is faster or **multiprocessing**. Theoretically due to **GIL**, multiprocessing should be faster than multithreading as only one thread runs at a time. But I am getting **opposite** results i.e threading is taking less time than multiprocessing, what am I missing please help.

Below is the code of **threading**

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time

print_lock = threading.Lock()

def exampleJob(worker):
    time.sleep(10)  
    with print_lock:
        print(threading.current_thread().name,worker)


def threader():
    while True:

        worker = q.get()


        exampleJob(worker)


        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for x in range(4):
     t = threading.Thread(target=threader)

     print(x)
     t.daemon = True


     t.start()

start = time.time()


for worker in range(8):
    q.put(worker)


q.join()


print('Entire job took:',time.time() - start)
```

Below is the code of **multiprocessing**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def exampleJob(print_lock,worker):                 # function simulating some computation
    time.sleep(10)
    with print_lock:
        print(mp.current_process().name,worker)

def processor(print_lock,q):                       # function where process pick up the job
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        if worker is None: # flag to exit the process
            break
        exampleJob(print_lock,worker)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print_lock = mp.Lock()
    q = mp.Queue()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=processor,args=(print_lock,q)) for _ in range(4)]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()    

    start = time.time()
    for worker in range(8):
        q.put(worker)

    for process in processes:
        q.put(None) # quit indicator

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print('Entire job took:',time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)

Comment: no actually I knew the theory but was lagging in implementation the answer that I have accepted solved the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @zmbq threading will be slower only when you are doing a computationally intensive task due to the presence of GIL. If your operations are I/O bound and few other similar operations then threading will be definitely faster since there is less overhead involved. Please refer to the following blog for a better understanding of the same.

[Exploiting Multiprocessing and Multithreading in Python as a Data Scientist](https://medium.com/@parthasarathysubburaj/exploiting-multithreading-and-multiprocessing-in-python-as-a-data-scientist-e2c98b61997a?source=friends_link&sk=d532b1f7bd1ae6afdf22484c556e1e3f)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper test. `time.sleep` probably does not acquire the GIL, so you're running concurrent threads vs. concurrent processes. Threads are faster since there are no start-up costs.

You should perform some calculations in your threads, then you'll see the difference.

Comment: thanks @zmbq can you suggest what changes should I make